# Blur Image On touch Android

Tags: android, image, touch, blur

I am new to android and I want to blur image on finger touch.

I have searched some example but I found like based on seek bar value whole image get blurred.

But I want something like I can set radius of finger touch and then based on that touch, that portion of image get blurred.

**MYANSWER**

MainActivity1.java

here,MainActivity.java file contains bitmap that is passed from MainActivity.java .

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // button
    private ImageButton opacityBtn;
    // custom view
    private DrawingView drawView;
    private Object bmpimg;
    private ImageButton currPaint;
    Bitmap b;
    private int originalheight;
    private int originalwidth;
    public  Bitmap tem;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        Intent i1 = getIntent();
        String img = i1.getStringExtra("imgpath");

        Log.e("img", "" + img);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img);

        // get button
        opacityBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.opacity_btn);
        // listen
        opacityBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        // custom view instance

//      LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
//      currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
//      currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
        Log.e("mainactivity1", "" + b);
        // bmpimg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcimg, 100, 50, true);

//      Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
//      Point size = new Point();
//      display.getSize(size);
//      int width = size.x;
//      int height = size.y;
//      tem=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width,
//              height - 200, true);

        drawView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);

        // fetching height and width of device
        int widthPx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int heightPx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        // set new height and width to custom class drawing view
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) drawView
                .getLayoutParams();

        if (b.getHeight() < heightPx && b.getWidth() < widthPx) {
            params.height = b.getHeight();
            params.width = b.getWidth();
        } else {

            if (b.getHeight() > heightPx && b.getWidth() > widthPx) {

                params.height = heightPx;
                params.width = widthPx;
            } else if (b.getWidth() > widthPx) {
                params.width = widthPx;
                params.height = b.getHeight();

            } else {
                params.width = b.getWidth();
                params.height = heightPx;

            }
        }

        drawView.setLayoutParams(params);
        drawView.setCanvasBitmap(b, b.getHeight(),
                b.getWidth(), widthPx, heightPx);

        if(b.getHeight()<heightPx&&b.getWidth()<widthPx){
            this.originalheight=b.getHeight();
            this.originalwidth=b.getWidth();
        }else{

        if(b.getHeight()>heightPx&&b.getWidth()>widthPx){

            this.originalheight=heightPx;   
            this.originalwidth=widthPx;
        }
        else if(b.getWidth()>widthPx){
            this.originalwidth=widthPx;
            this.originalheight=b.getHeight();  

        }
        else{
            this.originalwidth=b.getWidth();
            this.originalheight=heightPx;   

        }
        }
        tem=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, originalwidth,
                originalheight, true);
        Bitmap bitmap=createBitmap_ScriptIntrinsicBlur(tem,40);
        drawView.firstsetupdrawing(bitmap);

//      drawView.setScree_w(width);
//      drawView.setScreen_h(height);

    }

    /*
     * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the
     * menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); return true; }
     */
/*  public void paintClicked(View view) {
        //use chosen color

        //set erase false
//      drawView.setErase(false);
//      drawView.setPaintAlpha(100);
//      drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());

        if(view!=currPaint){
            Bitmap bitmap=createBitmap_ScriptIntrinsicBlur(tem,40);
            drawView.firstsetupdrawing(bitmap);

//          ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)view;
//          String color = view.getTag().toString();
//          drawView.setColor(color);
//          //update ui
//          imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
//          currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
//          currPaint=(ImageButton)view;
        }

    }
*/
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.opacity_btn) {
            // launch opacity chooser
            final Dialog seekDialog = new Dialog(this);
            seekDialog.setTitle("Opacity level:");
            seekDialog.setContentView(R.layout.opacity_chooser);
            // get ui elements
            final TextView seekTxt = (TextView) seekDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.opq_txt);
            final SeekBar seekOpq = (SeekBar) seekDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.opacity_seek);
            // set max
            seekOpq.setMax(40);

            // show current level
            int currLevel = drawView.getPaintAlpha();
            seekTxt.setText(currLevel + "%");
            seekOpq.setProgress(currLevel);
            // update as user interacts
            seekOpq.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    seekTxt.setText(Integer.toString(progress) + "%");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

            });
            // listen for clicks on ok
            Button opqBtn = (Button) seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.opq_ok);
            opqBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bitmap bitmap=createBitmap_ScriptIntrinsicBlur(tem, seekOpq.getProgress());
                    drawView.setPaintAlpha(seekOpq.getProgress(),bitmap);
                    seekDialog.dismiss();
                }

            });
            // show dialog
            seekDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap createBitmap_ScriptIntrinsicBlur(Bitmap src, int radius) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Radius range (0 < r <= 25)
    /*  if (r <= 1) {
            r = 1;
        } else if (r > 25) {
            r = 25;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);

        Allocation blurInput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, src);
        Allocation blurOutput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript,
                bitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript,
                Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        blur.setInput(blurInput);
        blur.setRadius(r);
        blur.forEach(blurOutput);

        blurOutput.copyTo(bitmap);
        renderScript.destroy();
        return bitmap;*/



//here i can make radius up to 40 use for it below code

 int w = src.getWidth();
          int h = src.getHeight();
          int[] pix = new int[w * h];
          src.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

          for(int r = radius; r >= 1; r /= 2) 
          {
              for(int i = r; i < h - r; i++)
              {
                  for(int j = r; j < w - r; j++)
                  {
                      int tl = pix[(i - r) * w + j - r];
                      int tr = pix[(i - r) * w + j + r];
                      int tc = pix[(i - r) * w + j];
                      int bl = pix[(i + r) * w + j - r];
                      int br = pix[(i + r) * w + j + r];
                      int bc = pix[(i + r) * w + j];
                      int cl = pix[i * w + j - r];
                      int cr = pix[i * w + j + r];

                pix[(i * w) + j] = 0xFF000000 |
                (((tl & 0xFF) + (tr & 0xFF) + (tc & 0xFF) + (bl & 0xFF) + 
    (br & 0xFF) + (bc & 0xFF) + (cl & 0xFF) + (cr & 0xFF)) >> 3) & 0xFF |
                (((tl & 0xFF00) + (tr & 0xFF00) + (tc & 0xFF00) + (bl & 0xFF00) 
    +  (br & 0xFF00) + (bc & 0xFF00) + (cl & 0xFF00) + (cr & 0xFF00)) >> 3) & 0xFF00 |
                (((tl & 0xFF0000) + (tr & 0xFF0000) + (tc & 0xFF0000) + 
    (bl & 0xFF0000) + (br & 0xFF0000) + (bc & 0xFF0000) + (cl & 0xFF0000) + 
    (cr & 0xFF0000)) >> 3) & 0xFF0000;
                  }
              }
          }
          Bitmap blurred = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
          blurred.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
          return blurred;


    }
}
```

DrawingView.java

Here,DrawingView.java  contains canavas so we canput image on canvas and blur it.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

    // drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    // drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    // initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xFFC0C0C0, paintAlpha = 255;
    // canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    // canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    int originalheight,originalwidth;
    /**
     * @return the scree_w
     */

    private BlurMaskFilter blurMaskFilter;
    public int scree_w, screen_h;

    public void setCanvasBitmap(Bitmap bitmap1, int i, int j, int widthPx, int heightPx) {
        this.canvasBitmap = bitmap1;

        if(i<heightPx&&j<widthPx){
            this.originalheight=i;
            this.originalwidth=j;
        }else{

        if(i>heightPx&&j>widthPx){

            this.originalheight=heightPx-1; 
            this.originalwidth=widthPx-1;
        }
        else if(j>widthPx){
            this.originalwidth=widthPx-1;
            this.originalheight=i;  

        }
        else{
            this.originalwidth=j;
            this.originalheight=heightPx-1; 

        }
        }

    }

    public void setScree_w(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.scree_w = width;
    }

    public void setScreen_h(int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.screen_h = height;
    }

    // constructor
    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    // prepare drawing
    private void setupDrawing() {
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        //

        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint();
//      BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(canvasBitmap, 
//              Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);  
//      //color and shader
//      drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
//      drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);

        blurMaskFilter = new BlurMaskFilter( 5,
            BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

    drawPaint.setMaskFilter(blurMaskFilter);
    }

     public void  firstsetupdrawing( Bitmap bitmap){

        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        //

//      drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint();
//      BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(canvasBitmap, 
//              Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);  
//      //color and shader
//      drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
//      drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);

        blurMaskFilter = new BlurMaskFilter( 5,
            BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

    drawPaint.setMaskFilter(blurMaskFilter);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
//  drawPaint.setAlpha(paintAlpha);
    BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, 
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);  
    //color and shader
    drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);


    }
    // view assigned size
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // int i=canvasBitmap.getHeight();
        // int y=canvasBitmap.getWidth();
        Log.e("hiyt wid-------------------------", "" + scree_w
                + "dsgvdfg sunita u will be happy" + screen_h);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(canvasBitmap,originalwidth+1,originalheight+1, true);

        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    // draw view
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    // respond to touch interaction

    float x = 0, y = 0;

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        Log.e("getalph drawing view", "" + getPaintAlpha());
        float touchX = 0, touchY = 0;
        x = touchX;
        y = touchY;
        touchX = event.getX();

        touchY = event.getY();

        // respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            /*
             * if (x == touchX && y == touchY) {
             * 
             * drawPath.moveTo(touchX + 1, touchY + 1); } else {
             */

            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            // }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            /*
             * if (x == touchX && y == touchY) {
             * 
             * drawPath.lineTo(touchX + 1, touchY + 1);
             * 
             * } else {
             */
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            // }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            /*
             * if (x == touchX && y == touchY) {
             * 
             * drawPath.lineTo(touchX + 1, touchY + 1);
             * drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint); drawPath.reset(); }
             * 
             * else {
             */

            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            // }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        // redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    // return current alpha
    public int getPaintAlpha() {
        return Math.round((float) paintAlpha / 255 * 40);
    }

    // set alpha
    public void setPaintAlpha(int newAlpha, Bitmap bitmap) {
        paintAlpha = Math.round((float) newAlpha / 40 * 255);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAlpha(paintAlpha);
        BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, 
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);  
        //color and shader
        drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
    }

    public void setColor(String newColor) {
        invalidate();
        //check whether color value or pattern name
        if(newColor.startsWith("#")){
            paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
            drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
            drawPaint.setShader(null);
        }
        else{
            //pattern
            int patternID = getResources().getIdentifier(
                    newColor, "drawable", "com.example.drawingfun");
            //decode 
//          Bitmap patternBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), patternID);
            Bitmap patternBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sun);
            //create shader
            Log.e("drawing view pattern+getalpha", "" + patternBMP+"dsfsdsd"+getPaintAlpha());
            BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(patternBMP, 
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);  
            //color and shader
            drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please share your answer

Comment: @sujiths check Question i alreday gave answer

Comment: How can i reset this view? or any way to clear view and initialize it again?

Comment: how can I blur on touch with OpenGLES?

Comment: can you please add Your xml File (Design) for refrence ??