# How to blur and unblur on Touch Android

Tags: android, blur, ontouch

I'm new to Android.
Can anybody tell me, how should I blur an image during touching the it? And how is it possible to remove the blur from a blurred image?
I have found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937221/blur-image-on-touch-android) where I can blur the image but I don’t know how to remove it and furthermore I want to ask if there is any other way of blurring the images rather than what I have mentioned.

Comment: blurring image can be done with renderscript. why not keep 2 images original and blurred and show them accordingly?

Comment: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4640